# Janrain error: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, drupal-7, janrain

I'm trying to setup Janrain Engage with my drupal website.

- I have created a Janrain account
- I have setup the providers (including Facebook)
- I have installed and configured the module (Drupal 7)
- I have have everything showing on the login page as would be expected
- I have created a Facebook app

Everything seems to be fine but...

When I try to log in with facebook I get this error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here :(

Thanks
C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Comment: That post didn't help me as I dont even know where `redirect_uri` is nor did I fill that out. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I know you're using a third party framework to wrap around the Facebook API so may not be aware of exactly what's happening in the background, but the question i linked is almost certainly applicable. The `redirect_uri` parameter is on the request to the OAuth dialog (and also on other dialogs, but i assume this is in the auth flow). That URI must be derived from the URI you've configured for your app in the App Settings interface on developers.facebook.com - this is a security measure to protect users data from leaking to third parties in an auth flow

Comment: If you don;t mind, can you please show me a screen shot of exactly where that is in facebook app settings. I'm totaly lost. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://support.janrain.com/entries/470621-how-to-resolve-a-facebook-settings-error